# How I can make a count with a plus number be optional in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, count, addition

I am making a calculator in javascript but I want that the person can add as many number as he wants in the count but I can't put this on js and make it works with more than 3 numbers, in fact, i only works with 3 numbers, if you put less or more than that it does not work :( Could anyone help me ?

Here is the code:

```js
function add_fields(){
  document.getElementById('linee').innerHTML += '<input type="number" id="nx">';
}


function pluscount(){
  var number1 = n1.value;
  var number2 = n2.value;
  var numberx = nx.value;
  var result = eval(number1) + eval(number2) + eval(numberx);
  visor.value = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="n1">
<input type="number" id="n2">
<button onclick="add_fields()">+</button>
<div id="linee"></div><br>
<button onclick="pluscount()">Somar</button>
<input type="text" id="visor" disabled >
```

I think I have to use `++` but I can't think the way

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make this calculation all in one go. Instead, you need to use a loop and a variable as temporary result.

Here a bit of pseudocode to help you:

```
//This means "addNumber()" will be called when you click "button"
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", addNumber());

var result = 0;

function addNumber()
{
    var input_string = document.getElementById("inputField");
    var input = parseInt(input_string);

    //If the user added something that is not a number, dismiss it.
    if(isNaN(input)) return;

    result += input;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is not actual JS code, so you will need to make some adaptions. However, it should help you see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it, possibly more elegant than what I've done. The following seems to work though.

```html
<input type="number" id="n1">
<input type="number" id="n2">
<button onclick="add_fields()">+</button>
<div id="linee"></div><br>
<button onclick="pluscount()">Somar</button>
<input type="text" id="visor" disabled >

<script>
number_of_fields = 2;
function add_fields(){
    number_of_fields++;
    document.getElementById('linee').innerHTML += '<input type="number" class="field_add" id="n'+number_of_fields+'">';
}
    function pluscount(){
     var total = 0;
     for(var i=1;i<=number_of_fields;i++){
       total += parseFloat(document.getElementById('n'+i).value);
      }
        visor.value = total;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a class selector in this example, in which case you can add a class to all text input and then select them through the command
querySelectorAll ()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Make a small change to your code

1st change in the addFields function add the class that will stay in all the inputs

2nd change change add function

we will implement a loop to pass through all inputs with the class equal, we will create a variable to be responsible for adding the values ​​of the field soon after we can use the display for you to show the value of the sum!

Strong hug

```
<script>

function add_fields(){
 document.getElementById('linee').innerHTML += '<input type="number" 
class="teste">';
}

function soma(){

    //seleciona todos os campos com a classe teste
var teste = document.querySelectorAll(".teste");

    //variavel que vai somar os valores
    valor = 0;

    //faz o loop independete da quantidade de campos que existe dentro do documento
    for(x =0;x<teste.length;x++){
        valor = eval(valor) + eval(teste[x].value);
    }

    visor.value = valor;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Provide more contents to support your answer, adding merely a code snippet doesn't seems to be a good answer.

Comment: i'm change my answer <#